# How implement photo pose verification flow

Tags: node.js, mobile, camera, verification

[image]
I want to implement this process in my React Native app and node js, but I don't know where to start.

I have already connected the camera to my application and can take a picture of a person, what mechanism will verify whether the person’s pose matches or not? Will it be implemented on the front or on the back end? need your advice

I checked all over the internet, but I didn't find a solution.